# Push elements that don't have a specific class into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, push

I tried to make a function looking for elements that don't have class "check", in this case I got it. Then I wanted to push them into an array so I got length, but what I got wasn't what I expected, do you have any solution for this case?

PLESAE READ MY COMMENTS IN THE CODES

What i wanted is to get the length of list that does not have class "check"

```
const countUnactiveList =()=> {
  let list = [...todoList.children];
  let listArr = [];
  
  list.filter(child => {
    if(!child.classList.contains('check')) {
      console.log(child); //it works, i got the lists that does not have class "check"
      listArr.push(child); 
      console.log(listArr.length); //the output are 1 2 3 creeping down. But it should be 3
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.prototype.filter` returns a new array and you're logging the length in each iteration.

here's the fixed code:

```
const countUnactiveList = () => {
  const list = [...todoList.children];
  
  const listArr = list.filter(child => {
    return !child.classList.contains('check');
  });

  console.log(listArr, listArr.length);
  
  return listArr.length;
}
```

based on the function name, I think you're just interested in the count. You can return the length of the filtered array.

An alternate approach using reduce:

```
const countUnactiveList = () => {
  const list = [...todoList.children];

  return list.reduce((count, child) => {
    if(!child.classList.contains('check')) {
        count += 1;
    }
    return count;
  }, 0)
};
```

Comment: But why did my output code was showing the length one by one creeping down?

Comment: @ClipCartoon `listArr`'s length increases by one every iteration and you're logging it every time. You should log/return after the loop.